# Spring Project - Classworlds Configuration not specified

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

i'm new to Spring and Maven development and i'm making the example guides at: https://spring.io/guides.

In fact i'm trying to make a jar file with eclipse.

The guide im following is this one: https://spring.io/guides/gs/device-detection/

**INFORMATION:**

**System:** Windows 8.1 (x64) - i5-62000U @ 2.30GHz

**Im behind a proxy** - Its all set up and eclipse handles all dependencies succefully.

**Eclipse:** JEE Mars 2 (version 4.5.2)

**Java**: JDK 1.8.0_77

**JRE**:  JRE 1.8.0_77

**Maven:** 3.3.9

**M2E**: It's installed in my eclipse (comes with JEE version).

**STS**: i'm not using Spring Tool Suite Eclipse, only Clean JEE Eclipse.

**Environment variables:** JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME are set up and next i put my path.

**Windows PATH:**

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Progra~1\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin
```

**Context:**

I have created the project using the skip arcthetype selection and declare it clean with all the dependencies (following the example).

**POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>gs-device-detection</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**XML settings inside .m2 folder:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>MY_USER</username>
      <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
      <host>MY_HOST</host>
      <port>3128</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
</settings>
```

**Output from "mvn -version":**

```
C:\Users\MY_USER>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Progra~1\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

**The problem:**

So far i have been able to compile, run and create the standalone jar file service, but using in the Command Prompt (each one does perfectly):

```
mvn spring-boot:run
mvn clean package
```

**MY** problem is that when i do in Eclipse: Select Project > Run as.. Maven Build

Always get this Exception (no matter what i change or what i put or edit or reinstall in the system):

```
java.lang.Exception: classworlds configuration not specified nor found in the classpath at  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

**What i have done so far?**

**First**

Among all the things in the setting that i changed and re-installed all from zero (even Java and Maven).

I notice is the source code of this "Launcher" in the plexus which experts would understand but i put the link for sake of the all with the same problem:

https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-classworlds/xref/org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher.html

It seen's that im missing a classworlds.conf file at the maven installation directory, but i have no idea what should have inside or where to put it.

**Second**

I have also seen in GitHub some programmer that have their own classwordls.conf files but i dont understand where do i have to put it, or why this exception appears ONLY in Eclipse and not in the Command Prompt.

**Third**

Also i notice that some people have changed M2_HOME to M3_HOME (worked for some Mac users i saw around in StackOverflow).

**Forth**

I saw that others said it was a dependence on the "plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" located in M2_HOME\boot. I didn't understood why, Maven **"should"** handle all dependencies.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try NetBeans instead of Eclipse!  :- )

Comment: I wish i could, unfortunately where i work i have to stick myself to Eclipse.

Comment: So far i have seen problems with Eclipse Mars. I installed Luna and wordked with the dependencies. No results on Mars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future developers with this problem i will leave the changes i made to successfully download all the dependencies.

**First:**
There was a mirror in the company that was pointing a private ArtiFactory and downloading all the artifacts from there, some of the artifacts were not present to fulfill all the dependencies and that was the main reason why classworlds wasn't being donwloaded. I asked for support and configured it correctly. As an advice, check *ALWAYS* the location from were the dependencies are being downloaded, if they *ARE* actually there and if you have the necessary permissions.

**Second**
I changed my eclipse version to **Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)** and the connection problems stopped, i saw in other answers and the [Maven Integration for Eclipse Luna and newer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-luna-and-newer) page where were some bug reports for the version Mars 4.5.2.

**Last**
Has an additional step to avoid confusion with maven configuration settings, i changed the file location in Eclipse to point to the same file either for global settings and user settings. This way you know that if there's a problem with settings you have to check only one file.